# Creating Html table from array (Using prompt)

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Html. This is my first html javascript program and I have an issue with it.

A user puts his/her gpa CS102 A 3, Math101 B 3. Then, I put the data into an Array. The problem is when I create the table. I want to create a table like

```
THL100  B+  3
PHL107  A   3
ENG120  C+  3
MTH245  A   4
CSC221  A   3
```

What kind of loop I should use? I tried to use a `for` loop but it just doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```js
function load(){
    var data = [];
    while(true) {
        line = prompt("Enter course name, grade, and credit hours or click OK with no data to terminate");
        if(line == null || line == "") {
            break;
        }
        var values = line.split(/\s/);
        var citem = values[0];
        data.push(citem);

        var gpa = parseFloat(values[1]);
        var cgpa = [gpa];
        data.push(cgpa);
        var unit = values[2];
        var cunit = [unit];
        data.push(cunit);
    }
    return data;
}

function display(data) {
    var table=document.getElementById('result');
    table.innerHTML= "<tr><th> COURSE </th><th> GRADE </th><th> HOURS </th></tr>";

    for(var i in data){
        table.innerHTML +="<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td><td>" + data[i]+1 + "</td><td>" + data[i]+2 + "</td></tr>";
    }
}
data = load();
display(data);
```

```html
<table id="result" border="1px" class="classy">
</table>
<span id="text"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with accessing data not the loop, store each line as one element in the array, like object will be easy:

```
    function load(){
    var data = [];
    while(true) {
    line = prompt("Enter course name, grade, and credit hours or click OK with no data to terminate");
    if(line == null || line == "") {
    break;
    }
    var values = line.split(/\s/);
    var line = {
        COURSE: values[0],
        GRADE: parseFloat(values[1]),
        HOURS: values[2]
    };

    data.push(line); // now your array is [{COURSE: value, GRADE: value, HOURS: value}, {}, ...]

    }
    return data;
    }

    function display(data) {
    var table=document.getElementById('result');
    table.innerHTML= "<tr><th> COURSE </th><th> GRADE </th><th> HOURS </th> </tr>";

    for(var i in data){
    table.innerHTML +="<tr><td>" + data[i]["COURSE"] + "</td><td>" + data[i]["GRADE"] + "</td> <td>" + data[i]["HOURS"] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    }
```

**UPDATE**: yes the data is accessible inside the loop but for any variable

```
function display(data) {
        var table = document.getElementById('result');
        table.innerHTML = "<tr><th> COURSE </th><th> GRADE </th><th> HOURS </th> </tr>";
        let totalgp = 0; // if the total is for all courses define it here 
        for (var i in data) {
            let totalgp = 0; // if total grade for each course separately define it inside the loop
            if (data[i]["GRADE"] == "A") {
                var gp = 4 * data[i]["HOURS"];
                totalgp = totalgp + gp;
            }
            table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + data[i]["COURSE"] + "</td><td>" + data[i]["GRADE"] + "</td> <td>" + data[i]["HOURS"] + "</td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Is there any way to access GRADE data? For example I put GRADE is A. Then, can i do like 'if(data[i]["GRADE"]==A){
var gp = 4*data[i]["HOURS"];
totalgp = totalgp+gp;
}'

Answer (score 0):

The data should be stored in a 2-dimensional array to easily access the elements. The usage of for loop is right. 
To append the first row - 
`table.innerHTML +="<tr><td>" + data[0][0] + "</td><td>" + data[0][1] + "</td> <td>" + data[0][2] + "</td></tr>";`

similarly for 2nd row,
`table.innerHTML +="<tr><td>" + data[1][0] + "</td><td>" + data[1][1] + "</td> <td>" + data[1][2] + "</td></tr>";`